# Restful web service Endpoint not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

I am trying to build a basic REST web service that simply returns the current time and whenever I try to I get the following error whenever I try to call my service http://localhost:PORT/TimeService/CurrentTime:

> Endpoint not found. Please see the service help page for constructing
>   valid requests to the service.

What am I doing wrong? Below you can find all the code I am using. Thank You

Service1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfRestService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class TimeService
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "CurrentTime")]
        public string CurrentTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WcfRestService1
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes();
        }

        private static void RegisterRoutes()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("TimeService",
                new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(TimeService)));
        }
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't know off hand if that causes the execption but aren't you missing the `[OperationContract]` attribute on the CurrentTime method

Comment: Since .NET 4.0 you don't need the [OperationContract] anymore if you have either [WebGet] or [WebInvoke] for WCF HTTP services.

Comment: In which vdir/application is the global.asax located? If it's not directly at the IIS root, then the address should be http://localhost:PORT/ApplicationName/TimeService/CurrentTime

Comment: @carlosfigueira I am running this just by debugging it via Visual studio. When it loads the browser you can access it via http://localhost:PORT which just brings up all the files of solution.

Comment: Try to change to anonymous port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the best articles I found when I first started learning rest; I wish I was at work now I have the exact TimeService example but I just Googled and could not find the same code.

Tomorrow from work I will post a working example if you still need it.

http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx

Comment: That would be very helpful if you could post that.